# fstream::close() doesn't close file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream

I have a program that reads a set of files, closes them, and then attempt to delete them.

Sometimes (not always, but pretty often) the deletion fails with "*sharing violation*" error.

Using sysinternals process monitor, I saw that in these cases, the close operation wasn't reflected in the process monitor. It appears that sometimes the close system call is skipped for no apparent reason, and without any exception.

This is happening on a Windows 7 64bit machine using Visual Studio 2010.

Code sample:

```cpp
void readFile(string file)
{
    ifstream stream(file);
    string line;
    while(getline(stream, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    stream.close(); // this is redundant
}
```

Calling code:

```cpp
readFile(file);
if(remove(file.c_str()) != 0)
{
    cout << "file deletion failed" << endl;
}
```

Comment: A minimal testcase that reproduces the problem would be nice.

Comment: The relevant code is preety scattered, so copying all the relevant code is problematic. Also, the same code worked in other applications without any problem.

Comment: If the code is scattered then try to create a minimal code sample which will reproduce the problem, Most likely the problem will reveal itself to you when you do so.Without code the answers will be mere speculation and nothing else.

Comment: Are you using *pointer* to fstream? Or, maybe, you're using pointer to the class which has fstream has member?

Comment: If the code is too scattered to copy, it's probably too scattered to fix. Rein it in, simplify it, or learn to live with the crashes.

Comment: Nawas its a local variable. And I tried both implicit close (variable goes out of scope) and explicit close (using the close() method

Comment: Ophir Yoktan: if the variable went out of scope, that's a clear sign that there's another handle somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Mooing Duck. note that I also monitored the program using process monitor, and in the problematic cases the close system call wasn't seen (while in the good cases it was seen)

Comment: "The other handle" could easily be in your anti virus program checking what you just did to the file.

Comment: @Bo Persson: as I said, in most cases I see that a CloseFile operation was performed by the OS. In the problematic cases the operation wasn't performed by the OS.

Comment: Check if close fails. Read this as well:  [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2010/11/24/the-case-of-the-unexplained-sharing-violation.aspx)

Comment: Hy, I am experiencing the exact same behavior. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firsty your code  is lacking a `;`. Change this `cout << line << endl:`  to  this  `cout << line << endl;`

Here's a similar problem : [Any reason why an std::ofstream object won't close properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058917/any-reason-why-an-stdofstream-object-wont-close-properly)

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you are creating processes in-between using CreateProcess with bInheritHandles=true.  The new process will inherit the file handle and the file won't be closed by your main process as there is still an outstanding handle.  This may explain why you can't see the close operation in Process Monitor, the OS will close the file once all handles have been released.